# electronJS / Detect if foreign app is running (MacOS) (Sandbox) (MAS)

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, appstore-sandbox

Is it possible to detect in **electronJS** if are specific Apps are running on **MacOS**?

I want to check, if the *Mail.app* is open and its important, that the code works in Mac Apple Store (MAS) in **Sandbox Mode**.

In AppKit it is possible with
`var runningApplications: [NSRunningApplication] { get }`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications

I have wrote an code, which is working, but not in Sandbox, terminal commands are not possible:

```
 import { exec } from "child_process";
 ...

 isRunning(query: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cmd = `ps aux | grep "${query}" | grep -v grep`;


        exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {

            if (stderr) {
                reject(stderr);
                return false;
            }

            const lines = stdout.split("\n");
            let active = null;
            let pid = null;

            for (let index = 0; index < lines.length; index++) {
                const line = lines[index];

                if (
                    line.indexOf(query) !== -1 &&
                    line.indexOf(USERNAME) !== -1

                ) {
                    active = line;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (active) {
                const activeData = active.replace(/(\s+)/g, '\t').split('\t');
                pid = activeData.length > 2 ? activeData[1] : null;
            }

            resolve(pid);
        });
    });
}

this.isRunning('Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail').then(pid => {
    if (pid) {
       // kill the app?  
    } else {
        resolve(null);
    }
}, reject);
```

Has anyone a better solution for electronJS which works in MAS Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it:

```
const script = `
if application "Mail" is running then
    copy "true" to stdout
else
    copy "false" to stdout
end if
`;

exec(`osascript -e '${script}'`,  (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (stderr) {console.log("error", stderr); return;}

    console.log("stdout", stdout);
});
```